# Terminal that supports PgDn as option

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal-emulator

I would like a terminal for Ubuntu that supports <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> as the default functionality and to send them to the current Unix application when you press <kbd>PgDn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go back to the original terminal emulator, xterm, you can specify any actions for the keys. For example,

```
xterm -xrm 'XTerm*VT100.Translations: #override\n\
 ~Shift <KeyPress> Prior: scroll-back(1,halfpage)\n\
 ~Shift <KeyPress> Next:  scroll-forw(1,halfpage)\n\
  Shift <KeyPress> Prior: string(0x1b)string("[5~")\n\
  Shift <KeyPress> Next:  string(0x1b)string("[6~")'
```

This will scroll back a half page when the Prior key (page-up) is pressed without Shift, and insert the escape character and `[5~` when pressed with Shift.

Comment: Thank you!  I can't get this to work with shift.  What does ~ mean and why are shift written four times?

Comment: The `~` before `Shift` means "not shift", i.e. the shift key must not be pressed for this keypress to match.